# Get current stream URL out of Youtube Live API

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Is there any way currently to get the livestream URL out of the Youtube Live API? I can get the id, but there doesn't appear to be anyway to change that into a URL.

Not that it should matter, but I'm using the Python youtube client.

Comment: How are you getting the ID? I figured you'd be able to get the URL by just appending the ID to "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", does that not work? Also, what do you intend to do with the URL?

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't work at all. I'm using the official youtube library. Almost word for word this code: [link]https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list

Comment: What ID did you get?

Comment: hWbNrHQHvKK6paclLp7WYw1424300727241016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Edited]** I believe you got the `stream ID` instead of the `broadcast ID`. Check the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/python#retrieve_a_channel_s_live_video_streams) to see how to get your channel's `broadcast ID`.

> ...
>
> print "%s (%s)" % (broadcast["snippet"]["title"], **broadcast**["id"])

vs

> ...
>
> print "%s (%s)" % (stream["snippet"]["title"], **stream**["id"])

Although both get an `id` value, they are two different objects, therefore they should give you two different IDs. Appending the `broadcast ID` to the URL I mentioned in the comments will give you the URL for the stream.

**Update:** If you created a live event via your YouTube channel, you can just use `liveBroadcasts` list to get the `id`, which will also be the video ID that you can use to get the URL. If you created a liveStream via insert(), you must also create a liveBroadcast using insert() and bind it to the liveStream with bind() before you can use `liveBroadcasts` list to get the ID.

Comment: For more information on the difference between a live broadcast and a live stream, check [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/).

Comment: I linked to the wrong documentation, I'm actually using the livestream API, but the id still can't be plugged into the url and work.

Comment: I used the API explorer for liveBroadcasts.list and was able to successfully get my stream's ID. I authenticated my account, specified `snippet,id,contentDetails` for "part" and `true` for "mine". I was then able to append that ID to "youtube.com/watch?v=" to get the video URL for my stream when it was live and when it was completed.

Comment: I think the ID you got is the stream ID, not the broadcast ID as I previously mentioned. Did you create a liveStream using insert()? If so, you should next create a liveBroadcast via insert(), then bind your it to your liveStream so you can call liveBroadcast.list to get the ID, which will be the same as the video ID. That can be used to get your URL for the stream.

Comment: Hey thanks man, I flipped what you were saying in my head, but now that I've got that straightened out, it totally works! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I'll update my answer so it's clear for anyone who happens upon it in the future.